# Sass lighten function issue

Tags: function, sass

Well, I have a problem with Sass function `lighten()`, this is my code:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4{
    .par-#{$i}{
        background: lighten(#08725D, #{$i}0%);
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
}
```

I think it's pretty obvious what I want to do, I just want to go through that variable and increment the lightening of the bg color (while I increment the number in the class), but I have this error in console:

> error main.scss (Line 111: $amount: "10%" is not a number for `lighten')

I need help please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS for loop updating hsla lightness returns error $lightness: "96.77419" is not a number for \`hsla'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312338/sass-for-loop-updating-hsla-lightness-returns-error-lightness-96-77419-is-no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$i` contains a number. Keep using it as a number instead of using concatenation :

```
@for $i from 1 through 4{
    .par-#{$i}{
        background: lighten(#08725D, $i * 10);
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't even know how I didn't realize it... I'm a bit sleepy so XD but It works perfectly fine. Thank you.